# Creating single AMD module from many TypeScript classes compiled as AMD modules?

Tags: javascript, build, gruntjs, typescript, amd

I'm trying to create a single AMD library (module) file which is build out of many small files (TypeScript files compiled to JavaScript-AMD modules).

The problem is:

1. I have cyclic dependencies between classes. (Parent needs to know child and child needs to know parent)
2. I want to get rid of all the define() and require() calls, except for the main define for *"myLibrary"*

The main reasons to create a single file:

1. Load times (requirejs should not be used to reference all the small files)
2. Cyclic dependencies that can't(?) be resovled by AMD modules

My main questions is:

- *Is there a tool to do this?* r.js (grunt-contrib-requirejs) failed me by leaving all the interior calls to define() inside.

My current project layout is similar to the following example:

```
root
|-- myLibrary
|   |-- packageA
|   |   |-- ClassA1.ts
|   |   +-- ClassA2.ts
|   |-- packageB
|   |   |-- ClassB1.ts
|   |   +-- ClassB2.ts
|   |-- packageA.ts
|   +-- packageB.ts
+-- myLibrary.ts
```

The code of *myLibrary.ts* is simply:

```js
export import packageA = require("./packageA");
export import packageB = require("./packageB");
```

Which simply compiles to an AMD module like this:

```js
define(["require", "exports", "./myLibrary/packageA", "./myLibrary/packageB"], function (require, exports, packageA, packageB) {
    exports.packageA = packageA;
    exports.packageB = packageB;
});
```

The package files are structured in the same manner. For example packageA.ts looks like this:

```js
// Typescript source:
export * from "./packageA/ClassA1";
export * from "./packageA/ClassA2";

// Compiled as Javascript:
define(["require", "exports", "./packageA/ClassA1", "./packageA/ClassA2"], function (require, exports, ClassA1_1, ClassA2_1) {
    function __export(m) {
        for (var p in m) if (!exports.hasOwnProperty(p)) exports[p] = m[p];
    }
    __export(ClassA1_1);
    __export(ClassA1_2);
});
```

What is currently get:

```js
define("myLibrary/packageA/ClassA1",["require", "exports"], function(require, exports) {
    var MyClassA1 = (function() {
        // The content of the class ...
    })();
    exports.MyClassA1 = MyClassA1;
});
define("myLibrary/packageA/ClassA2", ...

// The other stuff ...    

define(["require", "exports", "./myLibrary/packageA", "./myLibrary/packageB"], function (require, exports, packageA, packageB) {
    exports.packageA = packageA;
    exports.packageB = packageB;
});
```

What I desire:

```js
define(["require", "exports"], function(require, exports) {
    //... The entire code of packageA without define or require.
    var packageA = ...;
    //...
    export.packageA = packageA;
    export.packageB = packageB;
});
```

Answer (score 2):

They already have a module bundling in [their roadmap](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Roadmap).

Since we're at TypeScript 1.6 at the time of writing, and they say it will be implemented in 1.7, you'll need to wait for vnext, that should be released pretty soon.

Comment: Well that is nice to hear, but that sadly doesn't solve my _current_ problem. I would really like to see how it could be done with the tools currently available.

Comment: @Niabot That's a big desire for most of us, and unfortunately there is no simple way to achieve what you want. You would need to develop it yourself. I was almost doing that, when they finally approved the module bundling for the next version, so I'll be waiting for that (it will be available next month, so, not a big wait). But let's see if someone comes with a miracle help here :)

Answer (score 2):

> Specifying --outFile in conjunction with --module amd or --module
>   system will concatenate all modules in the compilation into a single
>   output file containing multiple module closures.

See [outfile + amd](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What's-new-in-TypeScript#concatenate-amd-and-system-modules-with---outfile).

Answer (score 1):

Currently, you would need to utilise some other sort of AMD optimiser.  In particular you can use [r.js](http://requirejs.org/docs/optimization.html) which is part of the RequireJS project.  It will inspect your AMD modules and emit them into different layers.

Currently though, if you configure your TypeScript project to utilise UMD, the r.js optimiser does not recognise [properly your UMD modules](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/4952) so the only option is to target AMD for your project.

I think even when some sort of concatenation is added to TypeScript 1.7+, you may still want to use a tool that is more feature rich, like r.js, since it will allow better optimisation and control of an AMD app, as layers and dependencies can often be complex in a complex project.

Comment: I would use that option if RequireJS (r.js) was actually able to solve circular dependencies within AMD modules. But it Isn't! So i tried SystemJS which claims to be able to solve circular dependencies for the "register" format. But i run into the similar issues, because the typescript compiler emits a __extend function for every class.

Can't there just be a tool that just puts the entire library into a single file, removing all the package/dependency stuff? :(

Comment: @Niabot if you target your `.tsconfig` file to use Module System `none`, it will remove all the package/dependency stuff, won't it?

Comment: Yes, but then im not able to export classes anymore, which makes it impossible to have a package like structure.

 I want to create one library from many files, from which some classes and methods are exposed as part of the module. But i dont want that every part of that module is internally a module itself. Its more like combining a multitude of small modules to a big one, removing all the overhead of the module definitions, while still beeing able to live with cyclic dependencies. The java (sic!) compiler does this like forever and it would be just to perfect for this case.